# Really small operator redo panel pop-up using merge by distance

Tags: settings

Recently when I try to Merge by Distance, the pop-up window where you can edit the distance is so small that it is rendered unusable. How do I fix this? I don't know what setting I changed to enact this. I am running Blender 3.6 through Steam. [image: Picture of the small option window]

Comment: it happened to me with Blender 3.6 and opening a file created in Blender 4, maybe open a brand new 3.6 file and append the objects?

Comment: That fixed it! My Version of Blender auto-updated to version 4. It didn't save any of my preferences so I rolled it back to 3.6 for the time being. I exported the objects as STL files, imported them to a new file and it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having the same problem with a file I saved with 4.0 then opened with 3.6. Investigating